# Someone sent me ethers in multiple transactions and took away my matic tokens nd those ethers

Tags: transactions, tokens, ether, metamask, etherscan

Someone (address: `0xc18842D634A683e6Ea5392e3f9f23a6966C88371`) sent me Ether in multiple transactions and took away my Matic tokens and those Ether were sent to another account(address: `0x7BFb08454aE23bA16bfdfd8a9F541a1427941576`),all without my knowledge.The first account from where I received Ether has taken away all my Matic Tokens 
my account: `0x6C2471a35d659699D74166aCEFbe8C5A76e2a0f2`
I'm using metamask

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like someone has access to your private key. The only thing to do right now is to move all remaining funds off of that address and onto an account that only you know the private key to. You should no longer use the exposed address after the transfer.

Comment: But i had created this account recently and didnt use it anywer

Comment: @akiabi `0xc18842D634A683e6Ea5392e3f9f23a6966C88371` seems to be a sophisticated attacher. He hacked into at least [other 3 wallets](https://twitter.com/search?q=0xc18842D634A683e6Ea5392e3f9f23a6966C88371&src=typed_query). How did you generate your wallet, can you remember?

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/HOJGFgV) in case the tweets from the link above will be deleted in the meantime.

Comment: i created a metamask account for my project

Answer (score 0):

Use http://buildbear.io/ and create your own Testnet by forking Ethereum, Polygon, Binance, Optimism, Arbitrum, Fantom, and Avalanche chains, allowing you to test your projects on the actual Mainnet state.